# Is there a way to integrate CiviCRM with Magento?

Tags: extension, mailing

We're looking to replace MailChimp in our organisation as a number of people are questioning the cost.  One area we're using heavily is integration with Magento - automatically emailing abandoned carts, sign up to mailing list as part of checkout process, that sort of thing.  Is there a way to get this functionality in CiviCRM?

Comment: when you say "One area we're using heavily is integration with Magento", do you mean in terms of your Drupal or WP or something else?

Comment: Ah, in terms of MailChimp and Magento - MailChimp plugs into Magento and can automatically email abandoned carts after a certain period of time, allow you to email all customers who've bought a specific product or from a specific category, that sort of thing.  We'd like to be able to replace MailChimp with CiviCRM but retain that functionality.

Comment: There are purpose built Magento extensions for that sort of functionality. No need for mail chimp or civiCRM.

Answer (score 1):

this is possible to integrate, but you would need to develop an extension to do some of it.

eg you can create automatically a mailing and add the recipients, you can add users into a newsletter group....

to my knowledge, there isn't an out of the box ready to use extension that already does it, so you would need to develop it or hire someone to write the needed